# How to use the parallel command along with find command in bash

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnu-parallel

Trying to  process a large list of files (~1000+)
The follow is a script that I am using..

```
for i in (find ./ -type f "*.properties");  
    do
       native2ascii -encoding UTF8 $i $i ;  //java native2ascii
done;
```

This will take a really long time to complete. Wondering is there a better way that I can leverage the commend `parallel` or other command  in bash to shorten the time it takes?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: @shmosel I guess because `native2ascii` is from java.

Answer (score 2):

why not?

```
find ./ -type f "*.properties" | \
parallel -j 4 native2ascii -encoding UTF8 {} {}
```

`{}` is for the replacement of input, adjust `-j` to match your CPU utilization.

Comment: so putting in {} will act the same as the $i in for i in (find ./ ...) ?

Comment: `-j` defaults to number of cores. Do not quote {} twice. It is unsupported and will sometimes fail in newer versions. So use this instead: `parallel native2ascii -encoding UTF8 {} {}`

Comment: @OleTange thanks for the hit, i will examine the code and update later.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Just a follow up question, is there a way to do some string manipulation with the second {} ? let say the input file name is **test.properties** and I want the output file to be **test_new.properties** instead.

Comment: use perl: `{= 's/(\..+)/_new\1/' =}` @leungc70